# Готовые классы для обработки звука под Java

Tags: java, аудио, поиск-библиотек

Есть ли какие-то реализованные библиотеки классов под Java для работы со звуком?. Из функций требуется: воспроизведение, перемотка, пауза звука из распространенных форматов, а также изменение самих характеристик звука (частоты, амплитуда проигрывания, прочие функции преобразования звука). Заранее спасибо за любые решения.

Answer (score 3):

Из классики: [JavaTM Sound Programmer Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/sound/programmer_guide/contents.html).

Answer (score 0):

[JOAL](http://jogamp.org/joal/www/)

> Проект является эталонной реализацией Java привязок для OpenAL API.